# DATE and time SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update the date and time using my computer time and date.

I want to be able when the information was manipulated from any user form his computer time. For instance, 
How can I make this function to get that information...I wrote TODAY with the function to_date(...) I wonder how can I do that?
this is the SQL that I have so far.

```
UPDATE lora1app.ENG_PART_REV_JOURNAL_TAB 
set  TEXT ='from developer', DATE=to_date('TODAY','YYYYMMDDHH24:MI:SS') 
WHERE part_no ='147590'  and  
part_no in 
(SELECT part_no from lora1app.ENG_PART_REVISION_REFERENCE eprr  --We can use it to any OBJSATE 
 where eprr.OBJSTATE= 'Preliminary' and eprr.part_no='147590'  ) and TEXT is not null  
 and 
 PART_REV = (select max(PART_REV) from lora1app.ENG_PART_REVISION_REFERENCE eprr 
             where part_no ='147590' ) and 
 DT_CRE = (select max(DT_CRE) from lora1app.ENG_PART_REV_JOURNAL 
           where part_no ='147590'  )
```

One more time I want when this UPDATE runs ..I want the TIME and DATE when this happened... I am using SQL ORACLE DB

Comment: Can you use `Getdate()?`

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions207.htm#SQLRF06124

Comment: Do you mean something like this?   I used the GetDate() but what parameters I need to include in that function. I need that data be equal to the computer time and date.                                        
UPDATE lora1app.ENG_PART_REV_JOURNAL_TAB set  TEXT ='from developer',
DATE=Getdate('TODAY','YYYYMMDDHH24:MI:SS')
..............

Answer (score 2):

Use SYSDATE for oracle, GETDATE() for sql server.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions207.htm#SQLRF06124

Comment: The TimesTen database is not the "Oracle database". I fixed the link to the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`sysdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions207.htm#SQLRF06124)

```
UPDATE lora1app.ENG_PART_REV_JOURNAL_TAB 
  set TEXT = 'from developer', 
      DATE = sysdate
WHERE ...
```

If you want to be a bit more standard compliant, you can use `current_timestamp`

```
UPDATE lora1app.ENG_PART_REV_JOURNAL_TAB 
  set TEXT = 'from developer', 
      DATE = current_timestamp
WHERE ...
```